# How to send mousedown message to a component or control?

Tags: c#, winforms, sendmessage

Is there a way to send message (like mousedown) to a control?

[image]
My purpose is that when you click GridView, prevent mousedown behavior itself and bypass mousedown message to RepositoryItem.

Comment: @Dai I deleted it because I thought it was an ambiguous expression.

Comment: When you say "GridView", do you actually mean a `DataGridView`? What is a "RepositoryItem"? Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.

Comment: @jmcilhinney It is not important what GridView and RepositoryItem, but the key is you could send or do not a message to a control.

Comment: It is important because "sending a message" is nonsense. You don't send messages unless you're talking about external applications.  `MouseDown` is an event and a control raises that event when the user depresses a mouse button with the mouse pointer over that control. That's it, that's all. You don't send anything. Now, are you going to explain your problem or do you think you know more than the people you're asking for help? I wouldn't have asked the question if it didn't matter.

Comment: @jmcilhinney OK, thank you for your interest. They are components from  DevExpress that is 3rd party library. GridView and RepositoryItem is derived from Component in C# System library.

Comment: Please update your question with all the relevant information, including what you expect the user to do and what you expect the application to do.

Comment: You can implement `IMessageFilter` in your Form, track `WM_MOUSEDOWN`, check whether the intended recipient is your grid (`m.HWnd == [The Grid].Handle`); in that case, post the message to another Control and return `true`: this suppresses the current message, so the grid won't ever receive it

Answer (score 0):

From your question: "My purpose is that when you click GridView, prevent mousedown behavior itself and bypass mousedown message to RepositoryItem."

It sounds like you want to control the behavior of the Mouse Down event on the control. Right?

If that's the case, on the Winforms designer, look at the properties panel. On there is also a selection for the form events for a control. You can scroll down and find the Mouse Down event and add an event handler. Then do whatever filtering you need including not even processing the message at all.

You also mentioned that it's a DevExpress control. I recall that some of their controls were wired up a little differently so the DevExpress website might have some additional clues.